# Multiple proofs of $\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b}\geq\frac{3}2$

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, contest-math

Here is my question:

> Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R^+}$, prove that $$\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b}\geq\frac{3}2$$

Here is my solution:

From C-S inequality, we get $$\sum_{cyc}(a+b)\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a+b}\geq3^2,$$
which is equivalent to $$2(a+b+c) \sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a+b}\geq9$$
or $$\frac{a+b+c}{a+b}+ \frac{a+b+c}{b+c}+ \frac{a+b+c}{c+a} \geq\frac{9}2$$
or $$\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b}\geq\frac{9}2-3=\frac{3}2$$
QED.

Here is my problem:

My teacher said that this question could be done in a lot of ways, one of which is by AM-GM inequality. However, after observing the original inequality, I still couldn’t get a clue.

I am stuck since I completely don’t know where to apply AM-GM. I am thinking about substitute something in the original inequality with some new positive numbers and continue. Is my thought in the right direction?

In addition, other approaches without AM-GM will be appreciated as well. Thanks for help.

P.S.
I am new to Mathematics SE, so if my post can be improved, make sure to let me know through the comment section. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nesbitt%27s_inequality#Proof). You will find nine proofs; one among them uses AM-GM, whereas the most common one follows using AM-HM. By the way, welcome to MSE!

Comment: @Qwertyuiop  There are very many ways to prove it: C-S, AM-GM, Muirhead, uvw, Holder, SOS and more

Answer (score 3):

One answer using AM-GM.

From AM-GM, we obtain two inequalities:

1. $a^{\frac{3}2}+b^{\frac{3}2}+b^{\frac{3}2}\geq3a^\frac{1}2b$
2. $a^{\frac{3}2}+c^{\frac{3}2}+c^{\frac{3}2}\geq3a^\frac{1}2c$

Add them up and we get:

$$2(a^{\frac{3}2}+b^{\frac{3}2}+c^{\frac{3}2})\geq3a^\frac{1}2(b+c)\iff\frac{a}{b+c}\geq\frac{a^\frac{3}2}{a^{\frac{3}2}+b^{\frac{3}2}+c^{\frac{3}2}}$$

Therefore
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b+c}\geq\frac{3}2\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^\frac{3}2}{a^{\frac{3}2}+b^{\frac{3}2}+c^{\frac{3}2}}=\frac{3}2$$QED.

Note: This inequality is called [Nesbitt's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nesbitt%27s_inequality#Proof), and in this link you can see a variety of approaches (as already commented by Dr.Mathva). This approach isn't included in it, so I think you'll probably like this as well.

Comment: I had not seen this nice approach before! ... [+1]

Comment: i think this method is called isolated fudging

Answer (score 2):

Because
$$\frac{a}{b+c} - \frac{8a-b-c}{4(a+b+c)} = \frac{(2a-b-c)^2}{4(b+c)(a+b+c)} \geqslant 0,$$
so
$$\frac{a}{b+c} \geqslant \frac{8a-b-c}{4(a+b+c)}.$$
Therefore
$$\sum \frac{a}{b+c} \geqslant \sum \frac{8a-b-c}{4(a+b+c)} = \frac 32.$$
**Note**. In addition, you can see [45th-proof-Nesbitt.pdf](https://diendantoanhoc.net/topic/56229-bdt-nesbit/?p=255636) (Vietnamese)

Answer (score 0):

Using AM-HM, the result can be generalized. Given positive reals $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$, where $n \ge 2$, define
$$b_i = a_1 + \cdots + a_{i-1} + a_{i + 1} + \cdots + a_n$$
and let $A, H$ be the arithmetic and harmonic means of the $b_i$. Then
$$A = (b_1 + \cdots + b_n)/n = (n - 1)(a_1 + \cdots + a_n)/n,$$ whence $a_i = nA/(n-1) - b_i$. Using $A \ge H$ we get
$$\sum \frac{a_i}{b_i} = {\frac{nA}{n-1}}\sum \frac{1}{b_i} - n
= \frac{nA}{n-1}\cdot\frac{n}{H} - n \ge \frac{n^2}{n-1} - n = \frac{n}{n-1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

A clue as how to prove it using SOS as @Michael Rozenberg suggested in his comment.

First, if $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}^+$ the problem

$$
p = 2 a^3-a^2 b-a^2 c-a b^2-a c^2+2 b^3-b^2 c-b c^2+2 c^3\ge 0
$$

can be transformed in this one now with $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$

$$
p' = 2 a^6-a^4 b^2-a^4 c^2-a^2 b^4-a^2 c^4+2 b^6-b^4 c^2-b^2 c^4+2 c^6\ge 0
$$

The [Newton polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polytope) for $p'$ is

[image]

which represents in the index space the monomials composing $p'$. Now we can select a polynomial basis for the $p'$'s index space  as

$$
Z=\left\{c^3,b c^2,b^2 c,b^3,a c^2,a b c,a b^2,a^2 c,a^2 b,a^3\right\}
$$

with the property that the Newton polytope associated to $Z\cdot M\cdot Z^{\dagger}$ includes the Newton polytope for $p'$. Follows the Newton polytope associated to $Z\cdot M\cdot Z^{\dagger}$.

[image]

Here $M$ is a generic symmetric $(10\times 10)$ matrix. Now if $Z\cdot M\cdot Z^{\dagger}$ and $p'$ represent the same polynomial it should be verified

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 m_{10,10}=2 \\
 m_{10,9}=0 \\
 m_{10,8}=0 \\
 m_{9,9}+2 m_{10,7}=-1 \\
 m_{9,8}+m_{10,6}=0 \\
 m_{8,8}+2 m_{10,5}=-1 \\
 m_{9,7}+m_{10,4}=0 \\
 m_{8,7}+m_{9,6}+m_{10,3}=0 \\
 m_{8,6}+m_{9,5}+m_{10,2}=0 \\
 m_{8,5}+m_{10,1}=0 \\
 m_{7,7}+2 m_{9,4}=-1 \\
 m_{7,6}+m_{8,4}+m_{9,3}=0 \\
 m_{6,6}+m_{7,5}+m_{8,3}+m_{9,2}=0 \\
 m_{6,5}+m_{8,2}+m_{9,1}=0 \\
 m_{5,5}+2 m_{8,1}=-1 \\
 m_{7,4}=0 \\
 m_{6,4}+m_{7,3}=0 \\
 m_{5,4}+m_{6,3}+m_{7,2}=0 \\
 m_{5,3}+m_{6,2}+m_{7,1}=0 \\
 m_{5,2}+m_{6,1}=0 \\
 m_{5,1}=0 \\
 m_{4,4}=2 \\
 m_{4,3}=0 \\
 m_{3,3}+2 m_{4,2}=-1 \\
 m_{3,2}+m_{4,1}=0 \\
 m_{2,2}+2 m_{3,1}=-1 \\
 m_{2,1}=0 \\
 m_{1,1}=2 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

so the matrix $M$ is

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 2 & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} \left(m_{2,2}+1\right) & -m_{3,2} & 0 & -m_{5,2} & -m_{5,3}-m_{6,2} & -\frac{1}{2} \left(m_{5,5}+1\right) & -m_{6,5}-m_{8,2} &
   -m_{8,5} \\
 0 & m_{2,2} & m_{3,2} & -\frac{1}{2} \left(m_{3,3}+1\right) & m_{5,2} & m_{6,2} & -m_{5,4}-m_{6,3} & m_{8,2} & -\frac{m_{6,6}}{2}-m_{7,5}-m_{8,3} &
   -m_{8,6}-m_{9,5} \\
 -\frac{1}{2} \left(m_{2,2}+1\right) & m_{3,2} & m_{3,3} & 0 & m_{5,3} & m_{6,3} & -m_{6,4} & m_{8,3} & -m_{7,6}-m_{8,4} & -m_{8,7}-m_{9,6} \\
 -m_{3,2} & -\frac{1}{2} \left(m_{3,3}+1\right) & 0 & 2 & m_{5,4} & m_{6,4} & 0 & m_{8,4} & -\frac{1}{2} \left(m_{7,7}+1\right) & -m_{9,7} \\
 0 & m_{5,2} & m_{5,3} & m_{5,4} & m_{5,5} & m_{6,5} & m_{7,5} & m_{8,5} & m_{9,5} & -\frac{1}{2} \left(m_{8,8}+1\right) \\
 -m_{5,2} & m_{6,2} & m_{6,3} & m_{6,4} & m_{6,5} & m_{6,6} & m_{7,6} & m_{8,6} & m_{9,6} & -m_{9,8} \\
 -m_{5,3}-m_{6,2} & -m_{5,4}-m_{6,3} & -m_{6,4} & 0 & m_{7,5} & m_{7,6} & m_{7,7} & m_{8,7} & m_{9,7} & -\frac{1}{2} \left(m_{9,9}+1\right) \\
 -\frac{1}{2} \left(m_{5,5}+1\right) & m_{8,2} & m_{8,3} & m_{8,4} & m_{8,5} & m_{8,6} & m_{8,7} & m_{8,8} & m_{9,8} & 0 \\
 -m_{6,5}-m_{8,2} & -\frac{m_{6,6}}{2}-m_{7,5}-m_{8,3} & -m_{7,6}-m_{8,4} & -\frac{1}{2} \left(m_{7,7}+1\right) & m_{9,5} & m_{9,6} & m_{9,7} & m_{9,8} &
   m_{9,9} & 0 \\
 -m_{8,5} & -m_{8,6}-m_{9,5} & -m_{8,7}-m_{9,6} & -m_{9,7} & -\frac{1}{2} \left(m_{8,8}+1\right) & -m_{9,8} & -\frac{1}{2} \left(m_{9,9}+1\right) & 0 & 0 &
   2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Now if we can find a [definite positive matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_symmetric_matrix) with this structure then the assertion $p'$ is proved. This verification can be done with  special  software packages as SOSTOOLS or CVX.